# 7z get total size of uncompress contents?

Tags: 7zip

How might i get the size of the contents of a zip/rar/7z file after full extraction? Under both windows and linux. I thought about using 7z l filename command but i dont like the idea of the filename interfering with the code counting the size of each file.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by the "filename interfering with the code counting the size of each file", but if you are going for a machine-readable format, you might be interested in the `-slt` command line option.

Answer (score 6):

The command line version of 7zip, 7z.exe, can print a list of files and their sizes, both compressed and uncompressed. This is done using the `l` flag.

Use this command:

```
7z.exe l path\folder.zip
```

You can also include wildcard which gives the overall total for all archives in a folder:

```
7z.exe l path\*.zip
```

Comment: Worth saying if you redirect the output of  `7z.exe l path\*.zip` to a text file then you get a very useful summation at the end of the text so you know what your total input and output file sizes are.

Comment: Also worth saying that the 7z command is available via the p7zip apt package on Ubuntu and many similar Linux systems, and also produces the described output.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve your filename problem, but may be good enough for others and myself (in cygwin):

```
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/7-Zip/7z.exe l filename.zip | grep -e "files,.*folders" | awk '{printf $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell:

```
'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l '.\folder-with-zips\*.zip' | select-string -pattern "1 files" | Foreach {$size=[long]"$(($_ -split '\s+',4)[2])";$total+=$size};"$([math]::Round($total/1024/1024/1024,2))" + " GB"
```

Or if you want to watch it total things in real-time.

```
'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l '.\folder-with-zips\*.zip' | select-string -pattern "1 files" | Foreach {$size=[long]"$(($_ -split '\s+',4)[2])";$total+=$size;"$([math]::Round($total/1024/1024/1024,2))" + " GB"}
```

If you run it multiple times, don't forget to reset your "total" variable in between runs, otherwise it'll just keep adding up

```
Remove-variable total
```