# get uncompressed size of zip

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip

I am trying to automate Oracle Database patching on **Windows** and one of the issues I have is with verifying that enough space is available on server(s) in order to copy and extract the patches.

What I need is a quick way to get the uncompressed size of a zip archive(Oracle Patches) in order to make sure there is enough space available for the script to copy and extract the patches.

I started from this thread:

[7z get total size of uncompress contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865892/7z-get-total-size-of-uncompress-contents)

Which seemed promising as per **samson7point1**'s answer:

```
'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l '.\folder-with-zips\*.zip' | select-string -pattern "1 files" | Foreach {$size=[long]"$(($_ -split '\s+',4)[2])";$total+=$size;"$([math]::Round($total/1024/1024/1024,2))" + " GB"}
```

But the above does not seem to work for me, probably I am doing something wrong.

Starting from that thread I tried to develop something in powershell which would sum the "Size" column of 7z and I got to this powershell script:

```
function getsizeofzip
{
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::startNew()
$username = "yayo"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "yayo" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
$masina = "yayo"
Write-Host Gathering list of zip files to calculate extract size -ForeGroundColor yellow
$alabala = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression "&'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l -ba -slt Z:\Oracle\OraDB19c3\*.zip"} -Computer $masina -Credential $Credentials | Select-String "Size = "
Write-Host Saving output to file -ForegroundColor Yellow
$alabala >> vvv.txt
$total = 0
Write-Host Calculating extract size -ForeGroundColor yellow
for ( $index = 0; $index -lt $alabala.count; $index = $index + 2)
{
$temp = $alabala | Select-Object -Index $index
$size = $temp -replace "Size = " -replace ""
#$size
$total +=  ($size -as [int])
#Write-Host Current total $total
}
$stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes
$stopWatch.Stop()
Write-Host Totalul este ($total/1024/1024/1024)GB
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Gathering list of zip files to calculate extract size 

Saving output to file Calculating extract size

21.5341170483333 

Totalul este 4.49708485417068 GB
```

As you can see the following 7z command is executed:

```
'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l -ba -slt Z:\Oracle\OraDB19c3\*.zip"
```

-ba -slt parameters are for sorting command output, to get rid of headers atleast and I get the following output:

```
Path = 33808367\files\sqlpatch\33808367
Folder = +
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Modified = 2022-05-02 11:51:38
Created = 
Accessed = 
Attributes = D drwxr-xr-x
Encrypted = -
Comment = 
CRC = 
Method = Store
Characteristics = UT 0x7875
Host OS = Unix
Version = 10
Volume Index = 0
Offset = 251558554

Path = 33808367\files\sqlpatch\33808367\24758240
Folder = +
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Modified = 2022-05-01 13:25:40
Created = 
Accessed = 
Attributes = D drwxr-xr-x
Encrypted = -
Comment = 
CRC = 
Method = Store
Characteristics = UT 0x7875
Host OS = Unix
Version = 10
Volume Index = 0
Offset = 251558645

Path = 33808367\files\sqlpatch\33808367\24758240\rollback_files
Folder = +
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Modified = 2022-05-01 13:25:40
Created = 
Accessed = 
Attributes = D drwxr-xr-x
Encrypted = -
Comment = 
CRC = 
Method = Store
Characteristics = UT 0x7875
Host OS = Unix
Version = 10
Volume Index = 0
Offset = 251558745

Path = 33808367\files\sqlpatch\33808367\24758240\rollback_files\19.1.0.0.0
Folder = +
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Modified = 2022-05-01 13:25:40
Created = 
Accessed = 
Attributes = D drwxr-xr-x
Encrypted = -
Comment = 
CRC = 
Method = Store
Characteristics = UT 0x7875
Host OS = Unix
Version = 10
Volume Index = 0
Offset = 251558860

Path = 33808367\files\sqlpatch\33808367\24758240\rollback_files\19.1.0.0.0\javavm
Folder = +
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Modified = 2022-05-01 13:25:40
Created = 
Accessed = 
Attributes = D drwxr-xr-x
Encrypted = -
Comment = 
CRC = 
Method = Store
Characteristics = UT 0x7875
Host OS = Unix
Version = 10
Volume Index = 0
Offset = 251558986

....
...
```

As i didn't know how to format the table (i tried a bit) in order to only select the Size column ... I piped that output to Select-String "Size =" which now outputs:

```
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Size = 86652
Packed Size = 13750
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Size = 92973512
Packed Size = 12818027
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Size = 205157781
Packed Size = 58369063
Size = 209589951
Packed Size = 59788028
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Size = 205157781
```

Now I loop through this ( index+2) to get all values and sum them up. This works but ...

Problem with above script is that for a Oracle patch that has a compressed size of 1.6g and 10s of thousands of files it takes ... 23 minutes ... this is somehow too much and as I am not very good with powershell or optimization in general I am looking for some advices.

Can you help point me in the right direction with:

-Is there a faster way to sort the 7z output with powershell? I tried formatting the string output to a table for easier parsing but I did not succeed, Format-Table (I understand this is for output only) or any similar cmdlets are of no help, table is not sortable by default ...
-Is there maybe another native utility for Windows that can show the uncompressed size of a zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it removes the requirement to write and then parse a text file which is probably where most of the time is being spent. This solution streams the output of the 7zip command to a foreach object. Within the foreach loop we look for lines containing "Size = " and then process any matches.

```
#Configure variable to hold our result
$size = 0

#Call 7zip and stream the output to a foreach object
&'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' l -bso0 -slt "C:\Temp\oracle.zip" | %{

    #Match the string "Size = anything" in 2 capture groups one of which will contain the filesize
    if($_ -match "(^Size\s=\s)(\d+$)"){
        
        #Add the uncompressed filesize to our result variable
        $size += $matches[2] -as [int]
    }
}

#Show the result in MB
$size / 1MB
```

Comment: Perfect, took 20 seconds compared to 1 minute after optimizing my initial script to just dump the correct lines to a variable and then sum the keys. Thanks a lot, will use yours :P